# How to test a function that accepts a JSX.Element?

Tags: jestjs, jsx

I have a type:

```
type button = JSX.Element | null;
```

and a function:

```
 const getFirstButton = (buttonArray: button[], first: boolean) => {
  if (first) {
    return buttonArray[1];
  }
  return buttonArray.find(b => b !== null);
};
```

here is my test

```
 test('getFirstButton', () => {
      const buttons = // what goes here?
      expect(getFirstButton(buttons, false)).toContain('button_1');
 });
```

I need help with the second line on the test. How do i handle this?
Is this even possible?

Note: my test file is test.ts and I don't want to change it .tsx

Answer (score 0):

`JSX.Element` is an object created by JSX syntax, i.e. `React.createElement`.

It can be:

```
const buttons = [null, null, <p/>, <div/>];
expect(getFirstButton(buttons, false)).toBe(buttons[2]);
```

Notice that JavaScript arrays are zero-based, so `buttonArray[1]` is possibly a mistake that will be detected when covering `if (first)` condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My test file is .ts, not .js , So i get the following error: `Cannot find name 'p'.ts(2304)`

Comment: The error means that JSX isn't parsed as such. This depends on your setup but most likely it can be solved by naming the test .tsx, as JSX isn't valid JS.

Comment: That's my question: Is this possible inside a .ts file? (i edited the question)

Comment: It's possible but your setup should support this, and most likely the file should have .tsx extension.

Comment: `setup should support this` How?

Comment: Please, post your setup, including TS config. If .tsx already works then this means it supports.

Comment: I have many tsx files in my project that are working. But i still get the error!

Comment: The error is the same? *my test file is test.ts and I don't want to change it .tsx* - you need to rename it. It's semantically incorrect to use .js/.ts extension for files that contain JSX because it's not valid JS/TS. JSX is an extension over JS, not a part of ES specification. It depends on your setup whether it's possible to overcome this. Any way, the problem with extension differs from your original question about how it should be tested, consider asking a new question that shows your setup.